# Why doesn't webpack include assert.rejects when bundling (UMD library target)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

*You can use this repo as a starting point if you wish: https://github.com/goofballLogic/webpackery*

My code runs an assertion

```
const assert = require( "assert" );
assert.rejects( () => Promise.reject() );
```

which passes in node.js.

When I bundle this code using webpack and run from node (or e.g. in a browser) it produces the following output. Why?

```sh
> ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --entry ./test.js --output test.bundle.js --libraryTarget umd --mode development

Hash: d30ba0b02040a574f117
Version: webpack 4.33.0
Time: 200ms
Built at: 06/12/2019 10:50:56
         Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
test.bundle.js  51.8 KiB    null  [emitted]  null
Entrypoint null = test.bundle.js
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {null} [built]
[./test.js] 78 bytes {null} [built]
    + 6 hidden modules


> node test.js

webpack:///./test.js?:2
assert.rejects( () => Promise.reject() );
       ^

TypeError: assert.rejects is not a function
    at eval (webpack:///./test.js?:2:8)
    at Object../test.js (/Users/andrewgibson/src/webpackery/test.bundle.js:175:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/andrewgibson/src/webpackery/test.bundle.js:20:30)
    at /Users/andrewgibson/src/webpackery/test.bundle.js:84:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrewgibson/src/webpackery/test.bundle.js:87:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`asserts.rejects` is only available in NodeJS v10.x and above.